# bashrc export path problem

Tags: bash, path

I opened my `.bashrc` file using `nano .bashrc` in terminal. After that, at the end of the `.bashrc` file I added following lines

```
export PATH= "$PATH:$HOME/moltemplate/moltemplate” 
export PATH= "$PATH:$HOME/moltemplate/moltemplate/scripts”
```

after that, I restarted my terminal and I am getting like in the figure[image]

Now I don't understand in which path my `.bashrc` file is because I can't see anything `.bashrc` file by using `ls -a` command.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: You have a typo: There should be no space around the `=`.  Also, you do not need to `export` the `PATH` variable, as it is already an environment variable.  You also seem to be using "fancy quotes" (`”` rather than `"`), probably due to writing in a word processor or on macOS?

Answer (score 5):

`.bashrc` file will always be in your home folder which is in `~/.bashrc` path

Just add following to `~/.bashrc` and do `source ~/.bashrc`

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/moltemplate/moltemplate"
```

You don't need to add export in `.bashrc` and `~` in path means home folder of the user running command, .`bashrc` will always be in the root of your home folder. You can also use `$HOME` instead if `~` which will also point to your home folder.

You can't have white space after the `=` sign and you need to use `""` type of quotes instead of `"”` you used

Answer (score 1):

1. `export` sets a flag on a variable in the current context, making it available to sub-shells. This means it only has to be exported *once,* not every time it's changed.
2. Unlike most other languages, whitespace is used to separate what are misleadingly called "words". So `PATH= "$PATH:$HOME/moltemplate/moltemplate”`   is *two* words, but a variable assignment *must* be a single word. If you remove the space the assignment works, otherwise each of those words become a separate *parameter* to `export`. And since a colon-separated set of paths is definitely not a valid variable name, you get the "not a valid identifier" error.